# Piping variable names to rm with magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I got stuck trying to remove variables by name in a loop, and found it's not possible(?) to do this with Magrittr pipes:

```
eg.names <- unlist(lapply(0:4, function(x){
  eg <- paste0('example.var.',as.character(x))
}))

for (examplename in eg.names) {
  assign(examplename, 10)
}

library('magrittr')

for (examplename in eg.names) {
  examplename %>%
    rm(list = as.character(.))
  print(exists(examplename))
}

### Gives:

# [1] TRUE
# [1] TRUE
# [1] TRUE
# [1] TRUE
# [1] TRUE
# Warning messages:
#   1: In rm(list = .) : object 'example.var.0' not found
# 2: In rm(list = .) : object 'example.var.1' not found
# 3: In rm(list = .) : object 'example.var.2' not found
# 4: In rm(list = .) : object 'example.var.3' not found
# 5: In rm(list = .) : object 'example.var.4' not found

### Piping `examplename` to `rm(list = as.character(.))` also doesn't work...

### Working non-%>% version:

for (examplename in eg.names) {
  rm(list = as.character(examplename))
}
```

Is there something I should be avoiding doing in Magrittr here, or is there actually some way around it?

Comment: I am confused: why not use `rm(list = eg.names)`?

Comment: Like @tonytonov, I'm not sure why you would want to do this (Perhaps there's more context?).  But it appears to me to be an issue with the environment.  using `rm(list = ., enivr = .GlobalEnv)` in your `for` loop does what you want. (but be very careful when doing this, especially in functions)

Comment: it's a simplified example to show the principle of what didn't work - I didn't actually have a list `eg.names`, but had performed some string manipulation on filenames in this loop one at a time, after removing file extensions etc, but the context isn't really the point. @Benjamin that's really odd... if you pass it without magrittr piping then you don't need to specify `rm`'s environment :-/ do you have any idea why that changes? does magrittr usually make scope fragile like this?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the actual mechanics of `magrittr` to know what is happening in the scoping.  I simply read the error message from your question and understood that `example.var.0` wasn't in whatever environment `rm` was looking at.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine:

```
for (examplename in eg.names) {
  examplename %>%
    rm(list = .,envir=globalenv())
  print(exists(examplename))
}
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
# [1] FALSE
```